# MS Access VBA Format Excel Sheet Column as Currency

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

In the below code, I need to format column E & F starting with row(3) as a currency. Thanks!

```
            Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

            objApp.Visible = True
            Set wb = objApp.Workbooks.Open("template.xls", True, False)
            wb.Sheets(1).Rows(3).Delete
            wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = title
            'need to format column E & F as currency

            Set objApp = Nothing
```

Comment: why having a template with .xls extension ? should be .xlt

Comment: Is there a row in those columns where the formatting needs to stop? Is it acceptable to format the entire column? Is there something in rows 1 and 2 that is already formatted and shouldn't be changed?

Comment: Yes rows 1 and 2 are already formatted and should not change. I only need column E and Column F starting from row 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Range("E:F").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

or

```
Range("E:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

or

```
Range("E:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to format 2 cells, it's one line:

```
wb.Sheets(1).Range("E3:F3").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

If you want to format all cells below row 3, and assuming those cells aren't already populated, then you could use:

```
Range("E3:F3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

Comment: These cells are populated with numbers but excel converted them to text. How do I convert them back to numbers so I can format them to currency? Excel won't allow me to format text to currency. Thanks!